# Bootstrap Slider behind navigation bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

so Im using Bootstrap v3.3.7 with slider and navbar. But I dont want those white bars at the navigation. So I thought to put the Slider behind the navbar but I dont know why :3
Heres my code:(I dont know if the  Is all right but that was my first thinking to get the navbar a little bit down the page ^^ )
http://pastebin.com/E5wut2TU
Best regards Azoni

Edit: It should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSxUN.jpg but I dont know how to do it in Bootstrap.. Thx :3

Comment: Put full html, with body, and head.

Comment: Got it, but I have some problems with the paragraphs.

Comment: I'm not fully understand, what do you want to change in this file? Remove white breaks above and below nav?

Comment: Yeah, so you can see the slider behind the navigation bar and not those white stripes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try overwrite css in additional file:

```
.carousel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.carousel-inner>.item { 
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I changed it but nothing happened, same problem. Thx though

Comment: You must add this css after bootstrap.min.css and ctrl+f5